# Como mostrar un Toolbar temporal abajo de un UITableViewController en Swift Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Necesito mostrar un Toolbar de manera temporal en la parte de abajo de un UITableViewController, es decir, solamente cuando se seleccionen varias celdas para realizar acciones en forma masiva y luego ocultarlo.

Lo he insertado en el storyboard arrastrando directamente un (Bar Buttom Item) desde la librería de objetos a la parte inferior del UITableViewController y automáticamente me agrego un Toolbar quedando de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy seguro si esta es la manera correcta de realizarlo, pero lo que quiero lograr es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutarlo no se visualiza el toolbar, creo que es porque la tabla ocupa toda la pantalla.

Como es la manera correcta de agregar, mostrar y ocultar un Toolbar abajo de un UITableViewController ?

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes crear el toolbar programáticamente y jugar con las constraint por código, para ver si el
Bottom constraint de la tabla ocupa toda la vista puedes debuggear la vista y en la jerarquía poder ver los elementos ocultos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Creas Oulet de la constrain
@IBOutlet weak var botton: NSLayoutConstraint! 

//Ejemplo de como ocultar y mostrarla
 @IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if botton.constant == 0{
            botton.constant = 50
        }else{
            botton.constant = 0
        }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Gracias... esa fue la solución...

Comment: @Luis No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como la solución, de esa manera agradeces el tiempo que el usuario invirtió y ayudas a otros usuarios con el mismo problema.

Comment: @Bicho Disculpa pero como se hace eso ? marque un ticket en el lado izquierdo de la respuesta. Esta bien ?

Comment: Todo perfecto, gracias a los dos.